# Cannot find module even my path was correct

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

[image]
[image]

error even my path was correct

i just need to run simple node and that is the problem

```
[nodemon] app crashed - waiting for file changes before starting...   
[nodemon] restarting due to changes...
[nodemon] starting `node app.js`
node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:959
  throw err;
  ^

Error: Cannot find module './router/playlist'
Require stack:
- C:\Users\Alfi\Documents\Code\gigih\module2.3\app.js
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:956:15)
    at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:804:27)
    at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1028:19)      
    at require (node:internal/modules/cjs/helpers:102:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Alfi\Documents\Code\gigih\module2.3\app.js:3:24)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1126:14)     
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1180:10)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1004:32)
    at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:839:12)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (node:internal/modules/run_main:81:12) {
  code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
  requireStack: [ 'C:\\Users\\Alfi\\Documents\\Code\\gigih\\module2.3\\app.js' ]
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Path is incorrect, your `router` folder is inside `src` folder. So use `./src/router/playlist` instead.